# sqlite3 vacuum,How to use on cordova APP

Tags: android, cordova, sqlite, vacuum

I have a big problem with the command VACUUM to free the memory from delete´s SQL sentences.

Im making a Cordova Android APP, and i know when i use a DELETE SQL sentence the space of the app don't down,... the space persist like a fragment HardDisk.

Then, i see that VACUUM can compact my DB, but i have a problem!

I use SQLite3, and VACUUM in all sites say that can´t execute in a transaction, like this:

```
var db = window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase({name:"maintenance", location:'default'});
db.transaction(function (tx) {
   tx.executeSql('VACUUM', [], function (tx, results) {
      alert('done');
 }, function (tx, error) {
      alert('error');
      alert(error.message);
   });
});
```

Ok, well, then, if i can't do in a transaction, could u tell me how can i execute a vacuum or auto-vacuum or something similar to compact the BD without write a line command? (remember that its a mobile app)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the GitHub Page](https://github.com/litehelpers/Cordova-sqlite-storage), you should be able to execute SQL outside of a transaction with `db.executeSql`:

```
db.executeSql("VACUUM", [], function(rs) {
    // ok
}, function(err) {
    // handle error
});
```

Comment: Hello,

Thanks for the help, i use that out of a transaction. The message "VACUUM DONE" in the ok block is show, but no result. The size of the data of the app its the same after and before of the vacuum.

Comment: @Armando How much data are you deleting? SQLite allocates space in multiples of its page size, so if you're deleting only a few rows, it won't free enough space to free a page.

Comment: That's right! I inserted 40000 rows to a bbdd table, my app data size on install is 484KB and with 40k rows is 2.18MB. Then with vacuum low my data size to 500KB. THX Colonel for your help :)